C# .NET Core 6.0 - Using Select when creating the IQueryable is slow, why?
We have a DataTier. Inside this DataTier are models that represent various tables/columns. These models are also associated with their respective DbContext (call it OurDbContext).
public class Foo
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

In a particular project, I want to add a field to Foo that's not in the table.
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}

I want to create an IQueryable for delayed execution.
IQueryable<Bar> queryable = OurDbContext.Foo.FromSqlRaw(someSQl)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(x => new Bar()
    {
        Field1 = x.Field1
        Field2 = x.Field2
        Field3 = null // null for now, we'll fill it in later
    });

When you look at the Intellisense, it says that .Select is returning an IQueryable.
But what I see happening is that the second we create the IQueryable, it's executing SQL (oops, I was wrong, just slow). We want to use an IQueryable with delayed execution, so we can skip/take 100 records at a time through the GUI.
But, the creation of the IQueryable is slow - which stinks.
EDIT:
What I notice is that it takes 10-15 seconds, while debugging, to execute that one line of code above, but if I make it this (no .Select), it's instantaneous (not even a second):
IQueryable<Foo> queryable = OurDbContext.Foo.FromSqlRaw(someSQl)
    .AsNoTracking();

What am I missing here?

just for fun can't you run this in a console app with stopwatch timinig around variant without select and variant with select and console log time elapsed?

Inspect console logs to see that mybe there was query send to the DB ?

Yeah, just add .ToQueryString() to your linq query and post the result here


But what I see happening is that the second we create the IQueryable, it's executing SQL

Then you see wrong. For example, you might be seeing it be executed in a watch window, or in the auto watch window in VS during debugging. However you are executing that query, you are jumping to the wrong conclusion.

Ok.  That's odd.  In my test environment, it takes about 10-15 seconds to execute that one line of code where I create the IQueryable.  I remove the .Select and it's instantaneous (making an IQueryable of course, so it could compile).  So, maybe this was a bad assumption?  But the 15 seconds vs 1 second tells me "something"

In other words, I wasn't looking at watch windows or auto watch windows, etc.  I was watching, by step debugging, one thing take 15 seconds and the other barely 1.  Wouldn't you say that the .Select was doing something odd here?
